# cpufreq-set fails with segmentation fault

Tags: cpu, cpufreq

I've a Ubuntu 16.04 running on my physical machine. Am trying to set all the cpu scaling governor to "performance".

Installed package versions are:

```
# dpkg -l | grep cpufreq
ii  cpufrequtils                   008-1                           amd64        utilities to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
ii  libcpufreq0                    008-1                           amd64        shared library to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
```

when I try the following command,

```
# cpufreq-set -r -g performance
Segmentation fault
```

And strace the above command shows

```
open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/related_cpus", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

I can't see these locations ( /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq ). Don't know what is missing.

cpufreq-info says "no or unknown cpufreq driver" why? what driver is missing?

```
# cpufreq-info 
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 1:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 2:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 3:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 4:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
```

Comment: Did you disable intel_pstate from grub? I got the same issue after doing it.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/816888/e3-1240-v5-cpufreq-info-says-no-or-unknown-cpufreq-driver-is-active-on-this-cp Has answered to my question as well.